# Printing arrays in bash

Tags: bash

I have two arrays in my bash script:

```
A=('AB' 'CD' 'EF' 'GH' 'IJ' 'KL' 'MN');

B=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7');
```

I want to be able to merge the arrays into a variable (say, in 'merge') so that an operation like:

```
echo $merge
```

...would print

```
(AB, 1, CD, 2, EF, 3, GH, 4, IJ, 5, KL, 6, MN, 7)
```

The length/size of the arrays need not be equal. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it close, but slightly different. Instead of finding the longest array, choosing the shortest is the only way to insure a 1-to-1 inclusion of elements from each array:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=('AB' 'CD' 'EF' 'GH' 'IJ' 'KL' 'MN')
B=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8')
len=${#A[@]}
declare -a combined

[ $len -lt ${#B[@]} ] || len=${#B[@]}  # find shortest array

for ((i = 0; i < $len; i++)); do

    [ -n ${A[i]} ] && combined+=( "${A[i]}" )
    [ -n ${B[i]} ] && combined+=( "${B[i]}" )

done

merge=$(printf " %s," ${combined[@]})
merge=${merge%,}
merge="($merge)"

echo $merge

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash array_merge.sh
(AB, 1, CD, 2, EF, 3, GH, 4, IJ, 5, KL, 6, MN, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A=('AB' 'CD' 'EF' 'GH' 'IJ' 'KL' 'MN')
B=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8')
len=${#A[@]}
[[ $len -lt ${#B[@]} ]] && len=${#B[@]}
out=""
for i in $(seq 0 $((len-1)));do
    [[ -n "${A[$i]}" ]] && out=$out","${A[$i]}
    [[ -n "${B[$i]}" ]] && out=$out","${B[$i]}
done
echo ${out:1}
```

Note:I give B 8 elements so that if the length of A and B is not the same, just put the rest elements of longer list to the tail of output

Explain:

the 3 and 4 line of code just find out the max length of two list.And then use a for loop to put each list's `i`th not empty item into the output.At last remove the first seprator `,`.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Avoid using `$(seq 0 $((len-1)))`. The c-style for is more appropriate: `for ((i = 0; i < $len; i++)); do`

Comment: Sure, the reason I mention it is at times you may need to adjust the index within the loop. Using `seq` eliminates that flexibility. The second point is it needlessly spawns another subshell to run `seq` where the builtin `for` loop syntax already provides that for you. You did a great job with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
A=('AB' 'CD' 'EF')
B=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8')
IFS=$'\n' 
m=($(paste -d\\n <(printf %s,\\n "${A[@]}") \
                 <(printf %s,\\n "${B[@]}" | head -c-2)))
merge=\("${m[@]}"\)
echo "$merge"
```

Output:

```
(AB, 1, CD, 2, EF, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```